# Imported object (purchased) not correctly displaying colors from .mtl file

Tags: import

I purchased the model below. Download comes with .obj .mtl and a .max.   I open the .obj and all I see is the model and no color or texture.  I check material properties and it looks like it is loading info from the .mtl file but it doesn't in any way correspond to the colors shown in the image.

I found two texture files hidden deep in an attached RAR.  Guessing the paths aren't finding those.  See image below.   Any suggestions on how to recreate the texture from the image?  I'm guessing the image on the left (lighter) is used as roughness map?

files can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12bzSSawDOr21ra6wc-0doXZrvt--9UtR?usp=share_link

[image: purchased model]

[image: result after import]

[image: two textures found in the DL folder]

Comment: nobody can help?  sad day for me

Comment: could you share the .max file as well? Might be an export problem

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I dropped the .max file into the folder.

Comment: I would use the left image texture for the *Specular* value and the right one maybe as a *Bump* map. Here is a try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM4mg.jpg - To get the light reflections as in the reference image, you need to turn down the *Specular* (gloss) a bit and make the chili pretty smooth (=low *Roughness* value).

Comment: Amazing!   Thank you!    Can you please show the nodes for how you did that???

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second material for the green stem part because there is no mask or base color image. If you select a vertice at the tip then you can expand the selection with *Select > Select More/Less > More* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad +</kbd>)

[image: screenshot 2]

For the stem and the chili, I've used the right image texture (*470354.jpg*) as a *Bump* map. The *Strength* is lower for the chili.

The left image texture (*istockphoto-466671100-1024x1024.jpg*) can be used for the *Specular* value for the chili. Here is a try:

[image: screenshot 2]

The white floor and the environment light (HDRI) create the pattern that you see on the chili. The horizontal light reflection is from 2 *Area* lights. To get the light reflections as in the reference image, you need to turn down the Specular (gloss) a bit with help of a *Map Range* node (`0.000` - `0.400`) and make the chili pretty smooth with a low *Roughness* value (`0.190`).

Do not forget to scale down the size of the chili, because imported it is a 500-m monster chili!

For *Eevee* enable `[X]` *Ambient Occlusion* and `[X]` *Screenspace Reflections*, use an HDRI with soft lights (*forest.exr*), and enable `[X]` *Contact Shadows* for the *Area* lights (`2 m` x `0.4 m`, `30 W`).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!   looks much better.